# Git error: ambiguous argument '***': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: flutter, github, flutter-dependencies

In my Flutter app I am getting the error: *stderr: fatal: ambiguous argument 'minor_changes': unknown revision or path not in the working tree*, when trying to do **pub get / pub upgrade**.

**minor_changes** - is the branch of my fork of bonfire package. **It's public**. The most interesting thing is that **this error does not occur on my other computer**. Windows is installed on both machines.

I spent two days looking for a solution to this problem, there were similar cases, but nothing helped me.

my dependency:

```
bonfire:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/rockstar4095/bonfire
      ref: minor_changes
```

error message:

```
Git error. Command: git rev-list --max-count=1 minor_changes
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: ambiguous argument 'minor_changes': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
exit code: 128

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
```